# Google Analytics counting sessions/views twice?

Tags: google-analytics

A site I work with recently saw a doubling of it's direct traffic as recorded in Google Analytics. There doesn't seem to be a obvious external reason for the increase (like some promotion or something) so I'm looking into a possible technical reason.

When loading the homepage and monitoring Real Time Traffic Sources, I see two hits in rapid succession each time I reload the page.

However I'm using the GA debugger extension in Chrome and it's only showing the two expected function calls: ga('create') and ga('send', 'pageview').

The site has other event tracking set up but each event is wrapped in an event listener in JS so they aren't firing automatically. And if they were they should show up in the GA debugger anyway

So I'm at a loss. I can't think of why this is happening, let alone just for direct traffic as opposed to other sources. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you describe. Even if I look at your page with with traffic analyzer, everything to be seems all right.